# Check if a services is installed using C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, service

I'm writing a C application which creates a Windows service. I'd like to check if the service is installed before trying to call the installation function, but I can't manage to find how to check it.

I've written the code above to try :

```
DWORD InstallMyService()
{
    char strDir[1024 + 1];
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;
    LPCTSTR lpszBinaryPathName;

    if (GetCurrentDirectory(1024, strDir) == 0)
    {
        aff_error("GetCurrentDirectory");
        return FALSE;
    }
    strcat(strDir, "\\"MY_SERVICE_BIN_NAME);
    if ((schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error OpenSCManager : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    lpszBinaryPathName = strDir;
    schService = CreateService(schSCManager, MY_SERVICE_NAME, MY_SERVICE_DESCRIPTOR,
                             SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                             lpszBinaryPathName, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error CreateService : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    return TRUE;
}
```

But this code does not detect if the service is still existing or not. Do someone have an idea of which function to call ? I found many posts talking about this, but not in C, only in C# or VB.

Thank you.

Comment: What's failing? It is the `OpenSCManager` call or the `GetServiceKeyName` call?

Comment: It seems, only when the service is still created, that the OpenSCManager fails.

Comment: Are you installing the software yourself? Why not create a registry key that tells you if it is installed or not? I don't think you can query for installed specifically. You can try to open the service with `OpenService` and if that fails it is an indicator that the service is not installed but could also mean it is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility would be to always attempt to [`CreateService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and if failure query `GetLastError()` and check if it is equal to `ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS`:

```
SC_HANDLE service_handle = CreateService(...);
if (0 == service_handle)
{
    if (ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS == GetLastError())
    {
        /* Handle service already exists. */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Handle failure. */
    }
}
```

This would require a slight change to your code from having two functions `InstallService()` and `CheckService()` to having one function (for example) `EnsureServiceInstalled()`.

Or, you could use the [`OpenService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which will fail with `GetLastError()` code of `ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`:

```
SC_HANDLE scm_handle = OpenSCManager(0, 0, GENERIC_READ);

if (scm_handle)
{
    SC_HANDLE service_handle = OpenService(scm_handle,
                                           "the-name-of-your-service",
                                           GENERIC_READ);
    if (!service_handle)
    {
        if (ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST != GetLastError())
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Failed to OpenService(): %d\n",
                    GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            /* Service does not exist. */
            fprintf(stderr, "Service does not exist.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened service.\n");
        CloseServiceHandle(service_handle);
    }

    CloseServiceHandle(scm_handle);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Failed to OpenSCManager(): %d\n",
            GetLastError());
}
```

Comment: I tried having only one function, but as far as the `OpenSCManager` call fails, I don't know if the `ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS` can still be appliable ?

Comment: No, the `OpenSCManager()` function is unrelated to a specific service. Can you obtain the `GetLastError()` value after `OpenSCManager()` fails. This will indicate what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite weird, now the call to OpenSCManager is OK, but now it's the CreateService that throw a 1073 error. I'll update my post to show you the CreateService call.

Comment: This explains that ! I read that it was something else :) Thanks then

Comment: No problem. Here is a link to the [Windows System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx) which you may find helpful.

Comment: There is a function called [`FormatMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) which you can use to translate a windows error code to a text description.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a yes / no answer whether a service is installed or note, use the following function:

```
bool IsServiceInstalled(LPWSTR ServiceName)
{
    bool serviceInstalled = false;
    SC_HANDLE scm_handle = OpenSCManager(0, 0, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    if (scm_handle)
    {
        SC_HANDLE service_handle = OpenService(scm_handle, ServiceName, SERVICE_INTERROGATE);
        if (service_handle != NULL)
        {
            wprintf(L"Service  Installed\n");
            serviceInstalled = true;
            CloseServiceHandle(service_handle);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(_T("OpenService failed - service not installed\n"));
        }
        CloseServiceHandle(scm_handle);
    }
    else
        wprintf(_T("OpenService couldn't open - service not installed\n"));

    return serviceInstalled;

}
```