# Check If a Windows Service is Installed or not? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I have written a windows service in C++, it works perfectly, now I want to add a feature that when I try to install it can first check that has it already been installed or not?

I have tried to look for ideas on how to do this task but there is not much help there. Most of the quesions and tutorials are for C# programmers and they are using ServiceController for their task, but I am unable to access any such class in C++.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx

the above link shows no example for this class in its example portion and says that:

"No code example is currently available or this language may not be supported."

Other Information:
I am using Windows 7 64 bit,
Visual Studio 2008,
Language is C++.

Any sort of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt the C++ code would be very different from the C# code. Try to look at the C# example, while checking methods and properties in C++.

Comment: as i said ServiceController is not accessible in C++

Comment: Might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868904/check-if-a-services-is-installed-using-c

Comment: No, there's no example on the `ServiceController` "front" page, but if you look at e.g. the static [`GetServices` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a.aspx) you will indeed see a valid "C++" example, meaning it's supported in C++/CLI and C++/CX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I leave the answer below, but actually this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9868904/21567) and I marked it as such.

You would use the [`OpenService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API. It returns a handle to the service, or `NULL` if the service in question does not exist (and `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`; there are other error reasons as well, so don't forget to check for that). Also, don't forget to call [`CloseServiceHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682028(v=vs.85).aspx) in case the call succeeds. This is what the .NET classes you mentioned use underneath as well.

You can also look this information up the [Database of Installed Services, in the Windows Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682544(v=vs.85).aspx).

Alternatively, you can run [external commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3883099/21567) (e.g. `sc.exe` or `Powershell`) form your installer that query this information.